# JanusGraph Indexes used only for lookup entry elements?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am not clear on JanusGraph (0.1.1 or upcoming 0.2.0) index behavior.

All indexes (Composite-index, Mixed-index and Vertex-centric-index) are used only to lookup entry point elements ?

For example, in the following traversal, indexes are use only at `has('Lang', 'name', 'python')` ?

```
g.V().has('Lang', 'name', 'python').in('use').has('person', 'age', P.gt(28)).toList()
```

If so, when an intermediate vertex has so many edges (super-node), JanusGraph must read so many elements from backend storage in order to filter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the initial lookup you can only leverage [vertex centric indexes](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#vertex-indexes) to improve the performance of traversals. You could, for example, duplicate the person's age property (also store it on the `use` edges and create a VCI over this property).

```
mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(uses, "usedByAge", Direction.IN, Order.incr, age);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to make Vertex centric indexes.